# Enable AWS JAVA JVM Cloudwatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/generating-sdk-metrics.html).

I've added `-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics=cloudwatchRegion=eu-west-2` to the java options. I also added the following dependencies in the maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.557</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.557</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.557</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.557</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The docker container runs fine on an ec2 instance with the correct iam role and policies. However, there are no CloudWatch namespaces for AWS SDK/Java as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Are you using ECS or running containers directly on ec2?

Comment: I am running the containers on ec2 swarm cluster

Comment: The docs state to use "-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics" if you're running on EC2. However, this will only work if your EC2 instances have an IAM Role attached to them and that IAM Role must have permissions to call cloudwatch:PutMetricData.

Answer (score 1):

This uses another dependency, change the *aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch* to *aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics*.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.557</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```